# Android AVD stuck on loading screen

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I've been trying to learn android programming and the emulator was working (sort of) before but now when I start it up it's stuck on the android loading screen. It's obviously not a question of patience because I've been waiting for about 2 and a half hours for this to load and it's STILL stuck on the android loading screen. Anyone know how to fix this? It's really starting to get on my nerves!

Comment: You can [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1554099/2688283) for ways to speed up the emulator.

Answer (score 1):

I've kind of solved the problem... apparently AVD's can't handle internal storage sizes larger than 1GB... even though the tutorial I'm watching says to add 10GB... Just FYI for anyone else having this same problem. I've seen it posted all over the place but this is one solution I haven't seen yet... It's kind of annoying but oh well.