# in an AVD I can't seem to get the sdcard to work

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I've created an AVD, got it to work fine except when I try to add an sdcard to it it doesn't work. I don't get an error message or anything but when I push files onto it, they don't show in the gallery. Someone on a different post suggested just downloading a pic off the internet instead of trying to push one on so I tried that and got an error message that said 
"No SD card

an SD card is required to download 01.jpg"

I've tried every solution I could find including going through the CMD and remounting the sdcard. Nothing worked. Any ideas? Why does it say "No SD card" when I already added it to the AVD? Why does it still say that after I've remounted it, which apparently is the only way to make it so I can push files onto it. That's how I got a different error message to go away! This thing has been one major headache after another! Once I solve or find a work-around for one problem another pops up almost instantly!!

Comment: Once close and reopen the emulator...it may works

Comment: I tried that but if I reopen it from snapshot it freezes and if I wipe user data I have to remount the sdcard to get it to even work in any way at all (if I don't remount I can't push files onto it I just get another error message, something about it being read-only).

Comment: I may have found the problem but once again, another one crops up (one I posted about earlier today). I entered the amount of storage space I wanted in the wrong place but entering it in the right place just leaves it in an endless loading screen when I try to start the AVD (it just keeps flashing "android" at me):

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28490372/android-avd-stuck-on-loading-screen?noredirect=1#comment45303032_28490372

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same problem i also faced but i got solution with following steps

1) AT the time of creating new AVD you have to give value in SD Card.

2) After starting the AVD insert the image that you want in AVD.

3) Next restart the AVD

**Note : Enter SD Card value from 10 MB onwards if you give more it may     not start AVD it will keep showing android.**

this solution is worked for me, hope this will helps you.